# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/tidy/Tidy , Maven project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven-2

I am trying to run java application built in Maven 2 from command prompt

On command prompt I did "mvn package" and got the jar in target folder of the application

Then I did:-

java -cp target/TempestApp.jar foo.App

And I get exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError: org/w3c/tidy/Tidy
      at foo.htmltoxml.HtmlToXMLConvertor(htmltoxml.java:29)
      at foo.app.main(App.java:35)
```

The application comprises of a JTidy. Who's dependency is mention in the POM.xml

Application runs fine in Eclipse but not from command prompt.

I even tried putting the JTidy jar in classpath variable

Comment: What maven dependency code do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let maven start your application with all the jars in the classpath. It is quite easy with the `exec-maven-plugin`.

Add this into your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.company.package.YourApplicationMain</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then when you want to build and execute in the same command:

```
mvn package exec:java
```

And if you just want to run the application:

```
mvn exec:java
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

`java -cp /path/to/jitidy.jar;target/TempestApp.jar TempestMainClass`

or

`java -cp /path/to/jitidy.jar -jar target/TempestApp.jar`

if the MainClass is set in Manifest.mf

Manifest.mf

...
Main-Class: package.to.your.MainClass <- NEWLINE!!!