# Running Java from Apple Script

Tags: java, applescript, classpath

I am very new to Apple scripting so please bear with me. I need to run a `.jar` file using `applescript`, the `jar` is not executable so I invoke the `class` like `com.path.to.myClass`. My Apple script looks like below-

```
display alert "You are about to start the image rename process." buttons {"OK", "Cancel"}
set theAnswer to button returned of the result
if theAnswer is "OK" then
    do shell script "java -classpath ./ImageRename_JAVA-1.0.0.jar:. com.mff.image.rename.Main"
else
    say "Exit"
end if
```

Both the applescript and the `ImageRename_JAVA-1.0.0.jar` are in the same directory, but when I run the script it gives me an error-

```
error "Exception in thread \"main\" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mff/image/rename/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mff.image.rename.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)" number 1
```

Am I setting the `classpath` wrong? If so, what is the correct way? Also, how can I add more `jar`s to the `classpath`?

When I run the below command from `Terminal` it runs just fine.

```
$ java -classpath ./ImageRename_JAVA-1.0.0.jar:. com.mff.image.rename.Main
```

I know that it can be done in a better way using `JAR Bundler` but I have no control over the `JAR` and its developed by someone else. Is there a way that I can include all the `JAR`s inside the application under `YourApplicationName.app/Contents/MacOS/Resources/Java/` directory and use those in the class path.

Comment: Take a look at this answer [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101240/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-tidy-tidy-maven-project/12106292#12106292). You also need to use ";" on win or ":" on linux/apple if you want to add more jars to the classpath

Comment: @Sal.. its essentially the same thing that I am doing. The command works in the `terminal` (command prompt) but fails when run from the `applescript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can guarantee what the working directory is in a `do shell script`, but you can work it out with something like this:

```
set scriptPath to the POSIX path of (path to me)
do shell script "SCRIPTDIR=`dirname " & scriptPath & "` ; " ¬
    & "java -classpath $SCRIPTDIR/ImageRename_JAVA-1.0.0.jar:$SCRIPTDIR com.mff.image.rename.Main"
```

To add extra JARs to the classpath you can take advantage of a shortcut provided by the `java` command whereby a classpath entry ending in `*` includes all `.jar` files in the given directory.

```
do shell script "java -classpath " ¬
  & "/Applications/Something.app/Contents/Resources/Java/\\* com.example.MyClass"
```

The `*` needs to be backslash escaped to protect it from expansion by the shell, and the backslash itself needs to be backslash-escaped when it is within an AppleScript string literal, hence the `\\*`.

Comment: Hi Thank you, I was able to make it work using the `*` wild card for multiple jars. However, I have a new issue- some of my jars are on a Windows network drive. So when I use something like this - `smb://user:pass@server/shared/jars/*` in the class path, it does not seem to work. Is there a way to include network paths in the jar file? (note- this works in Windows)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  You can use `mount volume "smb://user:pass@server/shared"` to attach to the share, and then refer to its files as `/Volumes/shared/jars/*` but that may be a bit fragile.

Comment: @IanRoberts... Thanks, yes I had to mount the network drive. Also, to your previous point the wildcard usage in `classpath` worked only on java 1.6, users have java 1.5 and it does not work in their system, so I had to include all my jars into the app `resource` and use `set thePath to (path to resource "jarname.jar")` to find the path. I also had to do change the directory (to that path) in the `do shell script` as `"JARDIR=$(dirname"&thePath&");cd $JARDIR"` and then use `java -cp $JARDIR/...:$JARDIR/...` and changing directory worked.